# How to stop a pseudo element from changing the width of other elements?

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-position, pseudo-element

I'm trying to put a pseudo element as a background image that simply crops at the document's width. However, when I put a background image in it keeps expanding the width of the document, making some other divs really wide.

Specifically, you can see from the screenshot that the nav is extending its width to accommodate the pseudo element's background image.

My attempt:[image]

I've seen it done, but am not what the difference is, as the code in the actual pseudo element is the same. An example:
[image]

HTML:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom">
        <div class="container nav-down">
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="/static/ScoopsLogo.png" alt="${out.global.siteName} Logo"></a>
                <p class="navbar-blog"><a href="https://blog.scoops.io/">Blog</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="scroll-progress">
            <div id="scroll-progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section id="home">
        <div class="home-1">
          <div class="home1-1">
            <h1>Sound smart at the dinner table</h1>
            <h5>Learning made easy & fun</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="home-lessons fade-in-up-static delay-2">
            <!-- List of Lessons -->
            <h5 class="text-center">NEW SCOOPS</h5>
            <div class="lessons-list">
            </div>
        </div>
     </section>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border-color: #e7e7e7;
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
.container {
    max-width: 600px;
}
.navbar-custom {
    .navbar-header {
      width: inherit;
      max-width: inherit;
    }
    .navbar-brand {
        img {
          width: auto;
          height: 100%;
        }
    }
    .navbar-blog {
      float: right;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 3px 10px 0 0;
    }
}
.home-lessons {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3%;
    @media (min-width: $screen-md-min) {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      padding: 20px 40px;
    }
    h5 {
      margin-top: -100px;
    }
    &::before {
      content: '';
      background-image: url(/static/Scoops-Icons.png);
      background-size: cover;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 200px;
      margin-top: -200px;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just answered a very similar question that [you put a bounty on over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44457687/6049581). In this case, I think that your best bet would be to either enforce a max width on your background-carrying pseudo-element, or drop the `overflow-x` on your document.

Below is a snipper of your CSS with the fix:

```
.home-lessons {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3%;
    @media (min-width: $screen-md-min) {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      padding: 20px 40px;
    }
    h5 {
      margin-top: -100px;
    }
    &::before {
      content: '';
      background-image: url(/static/Scoops-Icons.png);
      background-size: cover;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 200px;
      margin-top: -200px;
      max-width: calc(100% - 200px); /* HERE IS THE FIX */
    }
}
```

If that didn't work, the quick fix would be to go for this:

```
html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I've seen some people overkill it slightly by using, `html, body` as their  CSS selectors, this is up to you.

Comment: Thanks Frits. To clarify for myself & other people, why is it a quick fix & overkill to use html/body as the CSS selector for overflow-x:hidden;, and why should it be those selectors and not simply the parent of the pseudo element?

Comment: Hi @Chris. It's overkill because if your body has got `overflow-x: hidden;` it should never extend past `html` unless you specifically have a horizontally lined website - does that help? As for your 2nd question, it would be better having the `overflow-x:hidden` on the parent element, but only if your parent element is not smaller than the area that you are trying to reach with your pseudo-element. Often, the styling on the pseudo element is done in such a way that it sticks out past the parent element on purpose, but still needs to confirm to the document size. Does that help? :)

Comment: @Chris - don't forget to have a look at [your bounty question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44457687/6049581) - the question seems the same, but feel free to let me know if I left out anything there :)

Answer (score -1):

Parent element should use a `position: relative` whilst the child element uses `top: 0` and `left: 0`.

Like this:

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
}
.child {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: tried it - position:relative on the element, top: 0, left: 0 on pseudo. Still extending the width of the page. Overflow: hidden; works, however it then masks a different child div as well which I don't want to mask.